# Unit normal vector to the curve of a function at a point

Tags: functions, vector-analysis

How can I derive the formula for the normal unit-vector to the curve of a function at a given point $p$?

Answer (score 1):

If curve is represented by $f(x,y)=0$, then $\nabla f_{(x_0,y_0)}$ is normal vector to curve at point $(x_0,y_0)$

Comment: What's the name for that reflected $\Delta$?

Comment: 'nabla', it is.